# Why can't I shoot with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to make something cool with Python and Pygame for fun. I know a thing or two about Python in general but I'm quite a beginner with Pygame. 
So the problem is: I have created a movable player and a moving enemy. I want to make the player shoot when I press the spacebar. I loaded a .png image, defined a function for shooting, and made so that the bullet keeps moving once shot. For some reason when I call the function, it just does nothing. It doesn't even give an error. I know I can shoot only one bullet with the current code and whatnot, but I would like to just get the current code working as a start.

```
"""
player and enemy functions are defined above and work well, I didn't include
them in this post for the sake of saving everyone's time
"""

# bullet
bullet_pic = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bullet_pic_reverse = pygame.image.load("bullet reverse.png")
bullet_state = "nope"
def shoot(pic, x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "jes"
    screen.blit(pic, (x, y + 30))

player_dir = player_pic # direction of the player (left or right)
enemy_dir = enemy_pic # direction of the enemy
enemyX_change = 2.5
running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(back, (0, 0)) # background picture
    player(player_dir, playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemy_dir, enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # shooting
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if player_dir == player_pic:
                    bulletX = playerX + 100
                    bulletX_change = 20
                    bullet_dir = bullet_pic
                else:
                    bulletX = playerX
                    bulletX_change = -20
                    bullet_dir = bullet_pic_reverse
                shoot(bullet_dir, bulletX, playerY)

    # player movement
    hold = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if hold[K_LEFT] and playerX > 0:
        playerX -= 7
        player_dir = player_pic_reverse
    if hold[K_RIGHT] and playerX < 1100:
        playerX += 7
        player_dir = player_pic

    # enemy movement
    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if enemyX >= 1125:
        enemyX_change = -2.5
        enemy_dir = enemy_pic_reverse
    elif enemyX <= 900:
        enemyX_change = 2.5
        enemy_dir = enemy_pic

    # bullet constant movement
    if bullet_state == "jes":
        shoot(bullet_dir, bulletX, playerY)
        bulletX += bulletX_change
```

Comment: I am calling it outside the else statement. I call it every time when I press space, regardless of what the player_dir equals to. Correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with `pygame.display.update()`, you should put it always in the end of `while running:` loop. If you update display before calling `shoot()` background picture will be over bullet picture and you won't see it.

Another thing, you write `K_ESCAPE` instead of `pygame.K_ESCAPE` same with spacebar key. Does it work correctly for you? I didn't do anything with pygame for some time, maybe it's fine, but check it :)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution actually never crossed my mind haha but yes it works now. Also, I know a lot of people write it as `pygame.K_ESCAPE` but it works just fine without the `pygame.` prefix.